# Microsoft Advanced Hunting Query for a specific registry key

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I am looking for a query to get me a value of specific registry key for all laptops in the Defender.  Any help would be very much apricated .

Comment: Can you send a sample of the input data in a datatable() format and the expected output?

Comment: Here is what I have tried: 
DeviceRegistryEvents  
| where RegistryKey == "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\DELL\UpdateService\Clients\CommandUpdate\Preferences\Settings\Schedule"
| and RegistryValueName has "ScheduleMode"